# Configuring HTTPS for Netlify subdomain registered on AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, dns, amazon-route53, netlify

I have two websites hosted on Netlify. The first has the following domains

```
mydomain.io
www.mydomain.io
```

Netlify's one-click HTTPS works perfectly. In AWS Route 53 I have the following configurations:

```
NS mydomain.io

dns3.p08.nsone.net 
dns1.p08.nsone.net 
dns2.p08.nsone.net 
dns4.p08.nsone.net
```

and

```
CNAME www.mydomain.io
random-words-d12345.netlify.com
```

I have a problem with my second site. The domain in Netlify is as follows:

```
app.mydomain.io
```

In Route 53:

```
CNAME app.mydomain.io
```

I can't enable HTTPS in Netlify. I've also tried using `NS app.mydomain.io` with the same nameservers and no luck either.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are putting in the Netlify Nameservers in addition to keeping the Route 53 Nameservers or your old nameservers.

[image]

**If you want Netlify to manage your DNS**, remove the old NS entries and [follow the docs to enter your settings on `app.netlify.com`](https://www.netlify.com/docs/dns/).

**If you want to keep managing DNS from Route 53**, remove the Netlify NS entries and [follow the docs for Custom Domain DNS configuration](https://www.netlify.com/docs/custom-domains/#dns-configuration).

Comment: This is the same advice the Netlify helpdesk would have given :)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I have been through both of those documents multiple times. I do not have the old AWS nameservers set in addition to Netlify's DNS One nameservers.

To be clear, I can access app.domain.io, I cannot access it via https.

Comment: Actually, I had only changed the `domain.io` NS record, I didn't change the actual hostname configs under the "Registered Domains" section. I'll change those and hopefully that change will work.

Comment: Once you have them changed to Netlify, you can go in and add an entry for the `app.example.io` by adding a `CNAME` record for `app` with the value of your `app-site-name-here.netlify.com` in Netlify DNS

Answer (score 0):

For `app.mydomain.io` site, you don't need to enter whole site url as a CNAME. Just add
`CNAME app`, record in your primary DNS Name server. This will create subdomain. In your case I believe you are using Netlify's Nameservers DNS so need to add there.

Example:

[image: Example of cloud subdomain redirecting to netlify site]